# how to run mongo export on macbook?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am using mongodb Atlas (M0), which does not provide db backup feature. I am creating a nodejs script that will export all the collections automatically periodically.

So far I have done the following:

- created a programmatic api from my login.
- whitelisted my ip
- installed mongocli
- created a default profile using public and private api keys.

And command looks like this:

```
mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@mongoprojectname.lok0l.mongodb.net/${database} --collection ${collection} --type ${fileType} --out ${fileName} --profile default
```

I am not able to figure out how to run this command. If I run this command in my terminal I get this error: /bin/sh: mongoexport: command not found\n

Comment: As of MongoDB v4.4, `mongoexport` is part of the database tools and is installed separately. See [Installing Database Tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/#installing-the-database-tools-on-macos).